# PHP preg_replace confusion

Tags: php, regex, preg-replace

I'm currently scraping code from a website and I like to mark something, so I need to add a new class to a table row if a cell inside the row does match a pattern.

Structure of the table with the key to search for:

```
<tr><!-- other code --><td>MY KEY</td><!-- other code --></tr>
```

This should be transformed to the following:

```
<tr class="mark"><!-- other code --><td>MY KEY</td><!-- other code --></tr>
```

I tried the following:

```
preg_replace('#<tr>(.*)<td>MY KEY</td>(.*)</tr>#', '<tr class="mark">$1<td>MY KEY</td>$2</tr>', $html);
```

This is not working, and I can't get it to work. I tried some other variations with an eye on the PHP documentation about the function, but these were even worse.

**EDIT:** The problem is, that too many rows get marked even those which doesn't have this `<td>MY KEY</td>`.

Someone may help me?

Thanks in advance.

Regards

Comment: try adding a couple "?" limiter thingers in your regex:  `'#<tr>(.*?)<td>MY KEY</td>(.*?)</tr>#'`

Comment: ... my guess...   need the `s` modifier so that the "." will match `\n`s : `'#<tr>(.*?)<td>MY KEY</td>(.*?)</tr>#s '`

Comment: Doesn't work, too, but thanks for the answer. Tried with `#<tr>(.*?)<td>MY KEY</td>(.*?)</tr>#s`

Comment: You really need to consider using [DOMDocument](http://php.net/manual/en/class.domdocument.php) instead. Regex for HTML is not precise

Answer (score 0):

From the previous comments I understand you cannot show the full code because it holds private data.

Then I had the idea to ask you for only one example of an "alien" row (one being selected though not containing your "MY KEY". At this time I realized that in fact "MY KEY" itself might probably hold private data.

And it leads me to this hypothesis: **the real content of "MY KEY" might include some regex-significant characters**. If so, did you pay attention to carefully escape them?

Comment: For example, I use this (don't ask, why there's only `D` but, this is one of my real key (with which I'm testing)):
`$html = preg_replace('#<tr>(.*)<td>D</td>(.*)</tr>#', '<tr class="highlight">$1<td>D</td>$2</tr>', $html);`


And this get marked:
`<tr class="highlight"><td>&nbsp;12</td><td>1m5</td><td>&nbsp;</td><td>&nbsp;</td><td>&nbsp;rev</td></tr>`

The column I'm searching in is the second, so here: `<td>1m5</td>`

Comment: I'm sorry but I must ask about D! Because I don't understand at all: are you saying that using the pattern `'#<tr>(.*)<td>D</td>(.*)</tr>#'` **with exactly "D" as searched value inside** did return the element you report? Seems totally impossible! In the other hand, if you're searching for "1m5", why is it not included in your pattern, like this: `'#<tr>(.*)<td>1m5</td>(.*)</tr>#'`?

Comment: Yeah, that's why I'm confused. I'm searching **exactly for the 'D' values** but many other's get marked, too.

Comment: Hmmm... confused too, because this sounds like the only explanation is: you're doing things in another way than the one you've exposed. I'm not saying you tell us lies :) But I think the issue might reside in the fact that you expose what you believe see while you're "wrongly seeing"! So a suggestion: create a full-code test case (without any private data), control if it also gets wrong, then show it here entirely.

Answer (score -2):

This should work :

```
preg_replace('#<tr>(.*)<td>MY KEY</td>(.*)</tr>#', '<tr class="mark">$1<td>MY KEY</td>$2</tr>', $html);
```

Comment: that's the delimiter.  Can't remove it without replacing it with a different char.  I see no issue with using "#" here

Comment: No error message, but it's also adding the class to other table rows which doesn't even have the key.

Comment: The website holds private data, so I can't post the code.

Comment: I need the context of use, the problem is probably there.